# Set query to search all fields of a dojo datagrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I have a Dojo DataGrid with several fields. I'm currently setting the query to search one field at a time, like so:

```
grid.setQuery( {name:"Bob"}, {ignoreCase:true} );
```

However I would like the query to search all the fields at once. For example say I have three fields titled "name", "friend", "family". Let's say I only want the rows that contain "Bob" in any of the three fields to show in the grid. How would I got about doing that without three separate queries?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your store an `ItemFileReadStore` or a `QueryReadStore`?

If ItemFileReadStore you may be able to utilize the AndOrReadStore 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/data/AndOrReadStore.html

Otherwise, my best suggestion for a limited fetch store would be to adjust your back-end code to support filtering options such that when the store makes a POST(or GET), you parse out an array of fields that you want to search against, and the result set is returned accordingly.

You'd see something like

```
start 0
count 25
columnsToQuery : ["name","friend","family"]  //or perhaps a CSV string will do
columnOperator : "AND"
columnValue : "Bob"
```

You'd have to adjust the paradigm as per your business needs, but as long as the server can properly return the result set based on the filtering inputs this approach will work.

The call to generate such a request would be

```
grid.setQuery({
  columnsToQuery : ["name","friend","family"],
  columnOperator : "AND",
  columnValue : "Bob"
});
```