# How to filter dojo enhanced grid by external textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo

In my scenario, I am maintain a grid that need to be filter a particular column by the onchange event in a textbox. According to the text change grid should be filtered. I already able to use filter capability provided by the enhancedgrid and want to do it externally.

already imported 'dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid','dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore', dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Pagination', 'dojox/grid/enhanced/plugins/Filter',

This is in the external js file. A.js

```
            grid = new EnhancedGrid({
                store: new ItemFileWriteStore({
                    data: gridObject
                }),

                // "username, firstName, lastName, email, userGroupName, lastLoginValue, phoneNo, organization, status"
                structure: [
                    {
                        name: "User Login Name",
                        field: "username",
                        width: "84px"

                    },
                    {
                        name: "First Name",
                        field: "firstName",
                        width: "84px"

                    },
                    {
                        name: "Last Name",
                        field: "lastName",
                        width: "70px"

                    },
                    {
                        name: "Email",
                        field: "email",
                        width: "70px"
                    }
                ],
                rowSelector: '20px',
                minRowsPerPage: 5,
                rowsPerPage: 5,
                plugins: {
                    pagination: {
                        pageSizes: ["10", "25", "50", "100", "All"],
                        description: true,
                        sizeSwitch: true,
                        pageStepper: true,
                        gotoButton: true,
                        /*page step to be displayed*/
                        maxPageStep: 4,
                        /*position of the pagination bar*/
                        position: "bottom"
                    },
                    filter: {
                        closeFilterbarButton: false,
                        ruleCount: 2
                            //itemsName: "rows"
                    }
                }
            }, "gridee");

            console.log(grid);
            /*append the new grid to the div*/
            grid.placeAt("gridView");
            grid.startup();
```

--------------- function end ----------------

```
            UsersCtrl.prototype.filterGrid = function () {
                 var filterText = document.getElementById("txtFilter").value,                        innerDiv = document.getElementById("gridView").firstChild.getAttribute("id");

                 // innerDiv gave the grid id to be filtered.
                 dijit.byId(innerDiv).filter("username", filterText);// Dont no this is correct or not.

            };
```

-----------html file-----------------

Here angular and dojo both used. angular function also called successfully and able to get into the filterGrid function.

grid === UsersCtrl

```
   <input type="search" placeholder="Filter by Keywords" data-column="all" data-ng-   model="grid.searchText" data-ng-change="grid.filterGrid()" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox" id="txtFilter">

   <div id="gridView" style="width:100%; height:300px" align="center" class="claro"></div>
```

I am getting this error TypeError: object is not a function. Please help to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gladly I was able to get an idea after referring this [Set query to search all fields of a dojo datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034911/set-query-to-search-all-fields-of-a-dojo-datagrid)

import dijit/registry

```
        grid = registry.byId("grid");
        if (filterText) {
            grid.setQuery({"username": filterText + "*"});
        } else {
            grid.setQuery({"username": "*"});
        }

        //dijit.byId("grid").store.fetch(query: {username: filterText});
```